# Insert inline styles in the middle of a FreeMarker message

Tags: email, templates, freemarker

I'm using FreeMarker to template emails being sent out to notify users of new messages. What I'd like to do is be able to display a message with this formatting and emphasis:

"Hello User 1! You've received a new message *Message Title* from User 2"

To do this I'm splitting the message up into two bits, then putting the *Message Title* in a span in the middle with font-style: italic, like so:

```
${message("MsgNotificationEmail.receivedNewMsg1"), recipientName}
<span style="font-style:italic;">${msgTitle}</span>
${message("MsgNotificationEmail.receivedNewMsg2", senderName)}
```

Is there a neater way to apply styles in the middle of a message without needing to break it up like this?

Answer (score 0):

In a typical application of FreeMarker it would look like this:

```
Hello ${recipientName}!
You've received a new message <span style="font-style:italic;">${msgTitle}</span>
from ${senderName}
```

That is, you don't have `receivedNewMsg1` plus `receivedNewMsg2` plus a template, just a single template.