# FreeMarker+Tiles to generate email content

Tags: email, freemarker, tiles

I have freemarker templates for email content generation. I get the content for mail body using the following code snippet:

```
if( templateName!=null ) {
    Map<String, Object> templateVariables = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    templateVariables.put("BASE_URL", baseUrl);
    templateVariables.put("model", backingObj);
    Template template = freemarkerConfig.getTemplate(templateName);
    //logger.info("template["+template+"]");
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    buffer.append(FreeMarkerTemplateUtils.
        processTemplateIntoString(template,templateVariables ));
    mailBodyText = buffer.toString();
}
```

Everything works fine.

---

Problem: I have multiple templates and wish to integrate tiles so that I can share the same layout across all the templates.

Comment: Can't you just use a FreeMarker macro to make the common layout?

Answer (score 0):

Use a macro to create an [email template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7791715/insert-inline-styles-in-the-middle-of-a-freemarker-message), rather than Tiles integration:

```
<#macro content dispType="start">
<#--...-->
</#macro>
```